# How to select a thing that starts with X letter?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-like

Alright, so basically, i have a table structured like this

| ActorID | Name | Surname | Birthdate | Website |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

(with some data in it, of course)

And i want to select an actor depending on what their last name starts with.
So i know the SQL Request should be

```
SELECT ActorID FROM Actors WHERE Name LIKE '{Letter}%'
```

However, i want to do it with sqlite3 in python, and when i write it this way:

```
 cur.execute("""
                    SELECT name, surname FROM acteurs WHERE name LIKE '?%';
                
                    """,firstletter)
actors = cur.fetchall()
```

I get a syntax error "sqlite3.OperationalError: near ";": syntax error"

How should i modify it to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` placeholder must not be inside the single quotes.
The `%` wildcard must be concatenated to the `?` placeholder.
Also, you must pass `firstletter` as a member of a tuple:

```
cur.execute("SELECT name, surname FROM acteurs WHERE name LIKE ? || '%'", (firstletter,))
```